# Is there a known CGImageGenerator Error bug for iPhone 11 Pro Max on Device?

Tags: cgimage

I've been experiencing an issue with CGImageGenerator on the iPhone 11 Pro Max generating images -- it works on the simulator but not on the device. My question is if there are any known issues, my debugging has not revealed anything to me. Thanks!